# How to scan QRCode data into a browser?

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I am writing a website application and would like users to be able to input data into forms using a QR Code scanner. Is there a way to have a scanner hooked up to a PC that will input the data from the QRCode into a form after being scanned? I was thinking some kind of javascript might be required.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the scanner hooked up, and the drivers and software required to run it on the Computer? I think this would have to be sorted out long before you looked at getting it into a website...

Comment: Yea I think your right, I am looking to maybe purchase scanners that already do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a requirement to have a "QR scanner", but alternative will be to use a webcam.

With webcam, user will position QR code in front of camera and your web application will scan it. Usually it is done by embedding Flash app into your webapp, that can connect to webcam.

Here are couple of examples (please, note they use not QR tags, but some generic 2D barcodes):

Esquire
http://www.esquire.com/the-side/augmented-reality

USPS
http://thistimewithfeeling.com/augmented-reality-web-30-the-next-big-thing

In your scenario, you will need some kind of QR reader implemented in your web app to parse data into your form (instead of 3D rendering/tracking as in links above)